# contensis cms adding a javascript file to template

Tags: javascript, content-management-system

I'm working on the Contensis CMS system and I would like to know how to apply a javascript file to a template? I've tried to create a new template within the cms but it seems there isn't a way of using javascript.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What version are you running?

This should do the trick for R7.2 and upwards;

```
CurrentContext.Page.Scripts.Add("/path/to/my/js.js")
```

Or, if you want to add it to the bottom of the page, just before the closing body tag;

```
Javascript.StartUpJavascriptFiles.Add("/path/to/my/js.js")
```

Hope that helps.